# Clothes for shaved cats

Tags: cats, temperature

Our Persian cat was shaved yesterday and now it's become sensitive about touching and I think also he could become cold at home by this situation, his conditions now and before are like this:

[image]

So I like to know does he needs the cloth at this weather situation (temperature in Celsius). What temperature in home is good for him at this condition?

[image]

Also, what other method for helping him to stay warm do you know, which he also liked that and be available easily?

Comment: Since this is an international community, it would help to specify weather the temperature is given in °F or °C.

Comment: Unless there is a real need to shave your cat (overly matted coat--prevent this by brushing, medical procedures, etc), you should not shave him. His coat lets him regulate his temperature just fine on his own; there's no reason to "help" by taking it away.

Comment: Temp is in Celsius

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming your car is an indoor only cat.

Keeping your home at a temperature that feels comfortable to you should be ok. If you are cold, your cat will be too.

You can get your cat a [cat sweater](https://www.amazon.com/slp/sweaters-for-cats/s7zxtofajyds7tc) or you can make something out of a children's shirt or something similar. Be aware that the cat might not like it at all; then you should look at the other options. If you decide for a sweater, please also look at this [description how to safely put a sweater on your cat](https://www.petmd.com/cat/seasonal/sweaters-cats-do-they-need-them).

I recommend to give your cat sleeping places (blankets, beds) next to heaters where it will be warm.

If you feel he is particularly cold, you can make him a hot water bottle and wrap that in a blanket. He will probably like sitting on/next to it.

Otherwise you have to wait for the hair to grow back, but your cat should also adapt to the circumstances within a few days. The cat will search for warm spaces by itself, make sure they are available to it.